# What is the minimum number of Images for create_imagenet.sh in Caffe RC-4

Tags: caffe, lmdb

Hello I am running Caffe RC-4 and keep getting this output from create_imagenet.sh:

```
Creating train lmdb...
I0221 14:48:57.925828  8185 convert_imageset.cpp:86] Shuffling data
I0221 14:48:58.085487  8185 convert_imageset.cpp:89] A total of 28 images.
I0221 14:48:58.085688  8185 db_lmdb.cpp:35] Opened lmdb /home/caffe/images/ilsvrc12_train_lmdb
E0221 14:48:58.102860  8185 io.cpp:80] Could not open or find file /home/caffe/data/motd/train/
I0221 14:48:58.308913  8185 convert_imageset.cpp:153] Processed 27 files.
Creating val lmdb...
I0221 14:48:58.352946  8189 convert_imageset.cpp:86] Shuffling data
I0221 14:48:58.481848  8189 convert_imageset.cpp:89] A total of 0 images.
I0221 14:48:58.482054  8189 db_lmdb.cpp:35] Opened lmdb /home/caffe/images/ilsvrc12_val_lmdb
Done.
```

I have only 27 images in train and 8 in val

Why does it say could not open or find file and then says it has processed 27 files.

and for the Val it says there is 0 images when there are 8.

```
train.txt
n10000001_2955.JPEG 0
n10000001_7050.JPEG 0
n10000002_2179.JPEG 1
n10000002_2313.JPEG 1
n10000002_5631.JPEG 1
n10000002_6673.JPEG 1
n10000002_7309.JPEG 1
n10000002_8927.JPEG 1
n10000003_2926.JPEG 2
n10000003_3895.JPEG 2
n10000003_4498.JPEG 2
n10000003_6069.JPEG 2
n10000003_6442.JPEG 2
n10000004_1557.JPEG 3
n10000004_1759.JPEG 3
n10000004_2455.JPEG 3
n10000004_3370.JPEG 3
n10000004_3529.JPEG 3
n10000004_6396.JPEG 3
n10000005_1465.JPEG 4
n10000005_4328.JPEG 4
n10000005_4561.JPEG 4
n10000005_4640.JPEG 4
n10000005_5958.JPEG 4
n10000005_7610.JPEG 4
n10000005_7650.JPEG 4
n10000005_9843.JPEG 4
test.txt
n10000002_5602.JPEG 1
n10000002_7860.JPEG 1
n10000003_3676.JPEG 2
n10000003_4381.JPEG 2
n10000003_4578.JPEG 2
n10000003_7249.JPEG 2
n10000004_6958.JPEG 3
n10000005_7996.JPEG 4
```

My Dir settings in create_imagenet.sh:

```
EXAMPLE=$ROOTDIR/images
DATA=$ROOTDIR/data/motd
TOOLS=/usr/local/Caffe/caffe-rc4/build/tools

TRAIN_DATA_ROOT=$ROOTDIR/data/motd/train/
VAL_DATA_ROOT=$ROOTDIR/data/motd/val/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it needs val.txt instead of test.txt! Oops.